# Google Firebase Analytics implementation

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-analytics, code-snippets

Trying to implement Google Analytics on Firebase hosted website (WebApp of Firebase Project).

I tried Firebase suggested SDK snippets:

**Automatic:**

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="/__/firebase/7.16.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="/__/firebase/7.16.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Firebase -->
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

Tracking is not performed, no console errors.

**CDN:**

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "***************************************",
    authDomain: "test-project.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://test-project.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "test-project",
    storageBucket: "test-project.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "************",
    appId: "*:***************************************",
    measurementId: "G-**********"
    };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
```

Chrome - events get tracked, no console error;

FireFox - events not tracked console error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations.
```

Safari - events get tracked, no console error;

Edge - events get tracked, however - console error:

```
Tracking Prevention Blocked Access to storage for https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-app.js.
Tracking Prevention Blocked Access to storage for https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-analytics.js.
```

IE11 -  events not tracked, console error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'value'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After multiple unsuccessful attempts to get it works using "firebase.analytics()", I returned to the "old good" method using "gaObjects":

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

However in order to work it properly, in light of the recently announced by GA new setting: "cookieFlags (analytics.js"), I modified part of the snippet by adding "cookieFlags":

```
...
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {'cookieFlags': 'SameSite=None; Secure'});
...
```

Now it works flawlessly in all browsers without errors, showing statistics in "Google Analytics". Of course Firebase analytics console shows nothing, but at least I can view statistic of website hosted with Firebase in "Google Analytics"